# Can't create Audio frame with from nd_array

Tags: python, audio, webrtc, pyav, aiortc

I tried to use [pyav](https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV) to create an audio frame and I have an error that I can't fix for a few days now.

This is my custom audio class:

```py
 class CustomAudioTrack(MediaStreamTrack):
    kind = "audio"

    def __init__(self, rate=48000, channels=2):
        super().__init__()
        self.rate = rate
        self.channels = channels
        self._timestamp = 0

    async def recv(self):
        # Nombre de frames à lire pour 0.1 seconde de son
        frames = int(self.rate / 10)
        data = sd.rec(frames, samplerate=self.rate,
                      channels=self.channels, dtype=np.int16)
        sd.wait()  # Attendre que l'enregistrement soit terminé

        # Mise à jour des timestamps
        self._timestamp += frames
        pts = self._timestamp
        time_base = fractions.Fraction(1, self.rate)

        # Création de la trame audio
        audio_frame = av.AudioFrame.from_ndarray(
            data, format='s16', layout='stereo')
        audio_frame.sample_rate = self.rate
        audio_frame.pts = pts
        audio_frame.time_base = time_base

        return audio_frame
```

my error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\poppppp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiortc\rtcrtpsender.py", line 328, in _run_rtp
enc_frame = await self._next_encoded_frame(codec)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\poppppp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiortc\rtcrtpsender.py", line 270, in _next_encoded_frame
data = await self.__track.recv()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\documents\project\pythonProject\webrtc_tutorial\sadda_python\offerer.py", line 44, in recv
audio_frame = av.AudioFrame.from_ndarray(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "av\audio\frame.pyx", line 125, in av.audio.frame.AudioFrame.from_ndarray
File "av\utils.pyx", line 79, in av.utils.check_ndarray_shape
ValueError: Unexpected numpy array shape (4800, 2)
```

Do you have an idea of how I can fix this?

Comment: Actually I got this answer on github but I understand nothing : https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV/issues/1236
is someone can help me ? Thank you very much

Comment: The key part of the error is `ValueError: Unexpected numpy array shape (4800, 2)` which suggests `data` in the `recv` method is not 1. a numpy array, or 2. it is a numpy array, but it is not in the shape `(4800, 2)`. First step, what type and shape is `data` when it is created after `data = sd.rec(frames, samplerate=self.rate, channels=self.channels, dtype=np.int16)`?

Comment: data looks like that :   [[ 0  1]
 [ 0  0]
 [ 0  0]
 ...
 [-1  0]
 [ 0 -1]
 [ 0  0]]
and the shape is ( 4800, 2 ) but i can inverse it easily with data.T as ( 2, 4800)

Comment: I made a print exactly and it look like that : data :  [[ 0  0]
 [-1  0]
 [ 0  0]
 ...
 [ 0  0]
 [ 0 -1]
 [ 0  0]]
shape :  (4800, 2)

Comment: My apologies, `ValueError: Unexpected numpy array shape (4800, 2)` is actually saying that it is _**NOT**_ expecting a numpy array of that shape. So the question is actually "what shape _is_ it expecting". I would expect the number of frames to be a power of two, the nearest of which to `4800` is `4096` or zero pad to `8192`

Comment: You do not appear to be alone https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV/issues/523

Comment: A quick check of the package suggests you are using version 10.0.0 or older, so just be wary about breaking changes. Secondly, it seems the numpy array needs to be in shape `(number_of_channels, number_of_frames)`

Comment: actually I inverse it with the .T function a I said for shape the array like that ( nb_channel , nb_frames) but it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution,
The probleme was that when we give a numpy array to from_ndarray function it should be formated like that : [
[ 1] [ 1] [0] .... [ 1] [ 0]
]
so now I use pyaudio for listen the microphone but the numpy array has not the right shape so I use data.reshape(-1, 1) for reshape it perfectly
and here is the final custom class :

```
class CustomAudioTrack(MediaStreamTrack):
    kind = "audio"

    def __init__(self, rate=48000, channels=2):
        super().__init__()
        self.rate = rate
        self.channels = channels
        self._timestamp = 0

        # Initialiser PyAudio
        self.pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = self.pa.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                                   channels=2,
                                   rate=48000,
                                   input=True,
                                   frames_per_buffer=960)

    async def recv(self):
        frames_per_buffer = 960

        # Lire les données du stream PyAudio
        data = np.frombuffer(self.stream.read(
            frames_per_buffer), dtype=np.int16)
        data = data.reshape(-1, 1)

        self._timestamp += frames_per_buffer
        pts = self._timestamp
        time_base = Fraction(1, self.rate)
        # Préparation des données pour PyAV
        audio_frame = av.AudioFrame.from_ndarray(
            data.T, format='s16', layout='stereo')
        audio_frame.sample_rate = self.rate
        audio_frame.pts = pts
        audio_frame.time_base = time_base

        return audio_frame

    def __del__(self):
        self.stream.stop_stream()
        self.stream.close()
        self.pa.terminate()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I re edited the answer !